# What is the correct way to set a uniqueness validation on a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an `Organization` model that has_many `users` through `memberships`. What is the correct way to set up a uniqueness validation?

I have:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
  validates_presence_of :organization_id
  validates_presence_of :user_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :organization_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
end
```

When I try to create a membership:

```
o = Organization.find(275)
u = User.find(505)
m = o.memberships.new(user_id: u.id)
m.save
```

I get:

```
Membership Exists (2.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "memberships" WHERE ("memberships"."user_id" = 501 AND "memberships"."organization_id" = 275) LIMIT 1
```

I try running the exact query in postgres console and I get 0 rows results. `o.memberships` & `u.memberships` also reveals 0 results.

The only thing I can think of is that the uniqueness validation on `memberships` is wrong? What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The `m` returned by `o.memberships.create()` ( docs : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class ) already saved, so next `save` call is useless

```
o = Organization.find(275) 
u = User.find(505)
m = o.memberships.create(user_id: u.id)
m.save
```

Comment: hey sorry for the typo, I was manually typing out the code last night. I've tried `create` and `new` on `o.memberships`

Answer (score 0):

The organization_id is misspelled here:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :organziation_id
```

It should be:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :organization_id
```

Comment: Hey sorry for the typo. That is not the problem. I was manually typing out the code in frustration last night.